# Using Hibernate/EntityManager to update item required to have unique value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

I have a Spring Boot application using JPA and Hibernate to keep track of a list of `Recipe` objects. I have a small handful of successful JUnit tests, and I want to add a new test around *renaming* a recipe.

There's a business requirement that each `Recipe` must have a unique name.

Relevant code snippets:

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/recipe/{recipeId}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH)
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<String> renameRecipe(@PathVariable Long recipeId,
        @RequestParam(name = "name") String newRecipeName) {
    Recipe recipe = recipeManager.get(recipeId);
    recipe.setName(newRecipeName);
    recipeManager.save(recipe);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(recipe.toJSONString(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**Manager:**

```
@Repository
public class RecipeManager {
    ....
    public Recipe save(Recipe recipe) {
        System.out.println("save(): All recipes: " + getAll());
        if (lookupByName(recipe.getName()) != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("A recipe with this name already exists");
        }
        em.persist(recipe);
        return recipe;
    }
```

**Test:**

```
@Test
public void testRecipeCanBeRenamed() throws UnirestException {
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResp = Unirest.post("http://localhost:" + port + "/recipe")
            .field("name", "Spaghetti").asJson();
    long recipeId = jsonResp.getBody().getObject().getLong("id");
    jsonResp = Unirest.patch("http://localhost:" + port + "/recipe/" + recipeId).field("name", "Pesto Pasta")
            .asJson();
    jsonResp = Unirest.get("http://localhost:" + port + "/recipe/" + recipeId).asJson();
    JSONObject recipeObj = jsonResp.getBody().getObject();
    assertEquals(recipeId, recipeObj.getLong("id"));
    assertEquals("PestoPasta", recipeObj.getString("name"));
    assertNull(recipeManager.lookupByName("Spaghetti"));
    assertNotNull(recipeManager.lookupByName("Pesto Pasta"));
}
```

The **issue** with the test is that the `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown, as a result of what *I believe to be* Hibernate's local caching mechanism. When I call `setName()` on the retrieved `Recipe` instance in the `renameRecipe()` method, it's actually altering this property on the locally cached instance. So then when the manager attempts to `save()` the `Recipe`, it confers with its local cache, and sees **the property change** that has *not yet been persisted* to the database.

When running my unit test, in the `save()` method, immediately prior to the dupe check, I see:

```
save(): All recipes: [{"name":"Pesto Pasta","id":1}]
```

This also occurs when running live and testing through Postman.

How can I work around this issue? Do I need to introduce a business layer that checks for the *proposed* name prior to performing any modifications/persistence?

Comment: This won't solve your current problem but will prevent a new one: note that your *save()* method is calling [EntityManager.persist()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist-java.lang.Object-) which will try to create a new persistent entity and almost sure will throw an `EntityExistsException`. Given you actualy want to *update* an existent entity -> [What is the best way to update the entity in JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307578/what-is-the-best-way-to-update-the-entity-in-jpa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should check before modifying, instead of modifying then check. 
It's much more logical this way anyway, isn't it?

That said, you should also have a unique constraint in the database, because that's the only way to actually prevent duplicate names. With a unique constraint, you would get an exception (a different one, though), even with your way of doing.